# Jquery mobile Swipe event is not firing with Knockout.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, swipe

I have this html table which I need to navigate through pages on "swipe".

```js
onSwipeRight = function () {
 gridPager.CurrentPage(gridPager.CurrentPage() + 1);
},
                    
onSwipeLeft = function () {
 gridPager.CurrentPage(gridPager.CurrentPage() - 1);
},
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-bind="swiperight: onSwipeRight, swipeleft: onSwipeLeft">
 <tr class=" filterpanel">
  <td><span class="rowMove" style="background: none;"></span></td>
  <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: filtercus.name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></td>
  <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: filtercus.code, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></td>
  <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: filtercus.description, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" style="width: 295px"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

When I call the same JS methods on click event, the event fires successfully. But on Swipe it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You need to handle the swipe events through knockout, instead of handle it directly, use the `event` binding:

```
data-bind="event:{swiperight: onSwipeRight}"
```

Obviously, `onSwipeLeft`and `onSwipeRight` must be declared inside Your viewmodel.

Moreover, I believe that You are already aware that the first two parameters passed to Your knockout event handler function are

1. `data` (the ViewModel in context)
2. `event` (the jQuery event)

This means, You could also use just one function to handle both swipe directions, left & right:

```
onSwipe = function (data, event) {...
```

...because the jQuery.Event.type will be either `"swiperight"` or `"swipeleft"`.